# How can I get a list with the packages selected by apt-get autoremove?

Tags: apt, package-management, bash, scripts, text-processing

Is there any command that prints only the name of the packages that `apt-get autoremove` selects? I'm creating a script that updates the kernel, removes the old kernel and the unnecessary packages (`apt-get autoremove`), but I want to print on the screen the list of packages that will be removed by `apt-get autoremove`, how can I do this?

Comment: You should just be able to get it to run `sudo apt-get autoremove -y` and it should autoremove anything needed to be removed...

Comment: Try reading here, [This may be of help.][1]


  [1]: http://serverfault.com/questions/433250/how-to-get-the-list-of-packages-present-in-apt-get-autoremove

Comment: To get the list of packages without removing them actually you can do `sudo apt-get --dry-run autoremove`

Comment: I just want to get the name of the packages, not the entire output of the command....

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Since [as per your comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/652363/how-can-i-get-a-list-with-the-packages-selected-by-apt-get-autoremove/652531#comment937351_652363) you want to list only the packages that are going to be removed:

```
apt-get --dry-run autoremove | grep -Po '^Remv \K[^ ]+'
```

`grep` command breakdown:

- `-P`: Interprets the given pattern as a PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expression) pattern
- `-o`: Prints only the matched string instead of the whole line

Regex breakdown:

- `^`: matches the start of the line
- `Remv`: matches a `Remv` string
- `\K`: excludes the previously matched substring from the matched string
- `[^ ]+`: matches one or more characters not

```
$ apt-get --dry-run autoremove | grep -Po 'Remv \K[^ ]+'
libapache2-mod-php5
php5-readline
php5-cli
libonig2
libqdbm14
php5-json
php5-common
```

Comment: @GeekLynxAfonso, you don't need to use `sudo`with `--dry-run` option.

Comment: @jarno Makes sense, the fact that it was probably not needed didn't occur to me. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Actually you only need to filter the output of your

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --dry-run
```

command.

For instance you can do it with

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --dry-run  | head -n 5 | tail -n 1
```

Comment: Your command works too!! But I prefer the kos's command... But thanks in same!! :)

Answer (score 2):

No need for `apt-get` in modern apt versions. You can use

```
apt autoremove --dry-run
```

Comment: Thats necro-bumping. At the time of the question you **had to use** apt-get ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Using apt-patterns (see `man 7 apt-patterns`) one can simply do:

`apt list '?garbage'`